# I am always getting com.google.zxing.ChecksumException

Tags: android, zxing

None of the QR code are being decoded . Even the ones from zxing.
Is it also that the QR code is not being read at all ?

```
package com.pavan.secureqr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView;

public class ScanActivity extends Activity implements                                             

QRCodeReaderView.OnQRCodeReadListener {

private QRCodeReaderView decoder;
private TextView myText;
static final String tag="ScanActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_activity);
    decoder = (QRCodeReaderView) findViewById(R.id.qrdecoderview);
    decoder.setOnQRCodeReadListener(this);
    myText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.decodedText);

}


@Override
public void onQRCodeRead(String s, PointF[] pointFs) {
    myText.setText(s);
}

@Override
public void cameraNotFound() {

}

@Override
public void QRCodeNotFoundOnCamImage() {

}
```

}

Logcat:
04-18 22:30:06.359  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Initial camera parameters: antibanding=auto;antibanding-values=off,60hz,50hz,auto;auto-exposure-lock=false;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock=false;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize,whiteboard,blackboard,aqua;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=0.166667;focal-length=3.5;focus-distances=Infinity,Infinity,Infinity;focus-mode=fixed;focus-mode-values=fixed;horizontal-view-angle=54.9;jpeg-quality=95;jpeg-thumbnail-height=384;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=85;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=512x384,512x288,480x288,256x154,432x288,320x240,176x144,0x0;jpeg-thumbnail-width=512;max-exposure-compensation=12;max-num-detected-faces-hw=5;max-num-detected-faces-sw=5;max-num-focus-areas=0;max-num-metering-areas=1;max-zoom=60;metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);min-exposure-compensation=-12;picture-format=jpeg;picture-format-values=jpeg;picture-size=2592x1944;picture-size-values=2592x1944,2592x1456,2048x1536,1920x1080,1600x1200,1440x1080,1280x960,1280x768,1280x720,1024x768,800x600,800x480,720x480,640x480;preferred-preview-size-for-video=960x540;preview-format=yuv420sp;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p;preview-fps-range=15000,30000;preview-fps-range-values=(15000,15000),(15000,30000);preview-frame-rate=30;preview-frame-rate-values=15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30;preview-size=1280x720;preview-size-values=1280x720,960x540,864x480,800x480,768x432,720x480,640x480,576x432,480x320,384x288,352x288,320x240,240x160,176x144;scene-mode=auto;scene-mode-values=auto,hdr,auto_hdr;smooth-zoom-supported=true;vertical-view-angle=42.5;video-frame-format=yuv420sp;video-size-values=960x540,864x480,800x480,720x480,640x480,480x320,352x288,320x240,176x144;video-snapshot-supported=true;video-stabilization-supported=false;whitebalance=auto;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight;zoom=0;zoom-ratios=100,102,104,107,109,112,114,117,120,123,125,128,131,135,138,141,144,148,151,155,158,162,166,170,174,178,182,186,190,195,200,204,209,214,219,224,229,235,240,246,251,257,263,270,276,282,289,296,303,310,317,324,332,340,348,356,364,373,381,390,400;zoom-supported=true
04-18 22:30:06.359  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Supported values: [fixed]
04-18 22:30:06.359  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Settable value: null
04-18 22:30:06.366  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ surfaceChanged
04-18 22:30:06.491  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/PlatformSupportManager﹕ Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
04-18 22:30:06.493  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/AutoFocusManager﹕ Current focus mode 'fixed'; use auto focus? false
04-18 22:30:06.740  13672-13685/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1673K, 35% free 7173K/11032K, paused 10ms, total 29ms
04-18 22:30:06.982  13672-13684/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1761K, 35% free 7172K/11032K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
04-18 22:30:07.161  13672-14288/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1718K, 35% free 7172K/11032K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
04-18 22:30:07.375  13672-13685/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2290K, 41% free 6600K/11032K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
04-18 22:30:07.562  13672-14283/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1145K, 35% free 7172K/11032K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
04-18 22:30:07.817  13672-14288/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1674K, 35% free 7173K/11032K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
04-18 22:30:07.898  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ surfaceDestroyed
04-18 22:30:34.039  13672-13678/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-18 22:31:01.068  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/PlatformSupportManager﹕ Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface for SDK 9
04-18 22:31:01.111  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/GingerbreadOpenCamera﹕ Opening camera #0
04-18 22:31:01.457  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Screen resolution: Point(540, 850)
04-18 22:31:01.458  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Supported preview sizes: 1280x720 960x540 864x480 800x480 720x480 768x432 640x480 576x432 480x320 384x288 352x288 320x240 240x160 176x144
04-18 22:31:01.458  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Found best approximate preview size: Point(720, 480)
04-18 22:31:01.458  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Camera resolution: Point(720, 480)
04-18 22:31:01.463  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Initial camera parameters: antibanding=auto;antibanding-values=off,60hz,50hz,auto;auto-exposure-lock=false;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock=false;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize,whiteboard,blackboard,aqua;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=0.166667;focal-length=3.5;focus-distances=Infinity,Infinity,Infinity;focus-mode=fixed;focus-mode-values=fixed;horizontal-view-angle=54.9;jpeg-quality=95;jpeg-thumbnail-height=384;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=85;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=512x384,512x288,480x288,256x154,432x288,320x240,176x144,0x0;jpeg-thumbnail-width=512;max-exposure-compensation=12;max-num-detected-faces-hw=5;max-num-detected-faces-sw=5;max-num-focus-areas=0;max-num-metering-areas=1;max-zoom=60;metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);min-exposure-compensation=-12;picture-format=jpeg;picture-format-values=jpeg;picture-size=2592x1944;picture-size-values=2592x1944,2592x1456,2048x1536,1920x1080,1600x1200,1440x1080,1280x960,1280x768,1280x720,1024x768,800x600,800x480,720x480,640x480;preferred-preview-size-for-video=960x540;preview-format=yuv420sp;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p;preview-fps-range=15000,30000;preview-fps-range-values=(15000,15000),(15000,30000);preview-frame-rate=30;preview-frame-rate-values=15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30;preview-size=1280x720;preview-size-values=1280x720,960x540,864x480,800x480,768x432,720x480,640x480,576x432,480x320,384x288,352x288,320x240,240x160,176x144;scene-mode=auto;scene-mode-values=auto,hdr,auto_hdr;smooth-zoom-supported=true;vertical-view-angle=42.5;video-frame-format=yuv420sp;video-size-values=960x540,864x480,800x480,720x480,640x480,480x320,352x288,320x240,176x144;video-snapshot-supported=true;video-stabilization-supported=false;whitebalance=auto;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight;zoom=0;zoom-ratios=100,102,104,107,109,112,114,117,120,123,125,128,131,135,138,141,144,148,151,155,158,162,166,170,174,178,182,186,190,195,200,204,209,214,219,224,229,235,240,246,251,257,263,270,276,282,289,296,303,310,317,324,332,340,348,356,364,373,381,390,400;zoom-supported=true
04-18 22:31:01.463  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Supported values: [fixed]
04-18 22:31:01.463  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Settable value: null
04-18 22:31:01.576  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/PlatformSupportManager﹕ Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
04-18 22:31:01.578  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/AutoFocusManager﹕ Current focus mode 'fixed'; use auto focus? false
04-18 22:31:01.578  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ surfaceChanged
04-18 22:31:01.798  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/PlatformSupportManager﹕ Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
04-18 22:31:01.800  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr I/AutoFocusManager﹕ Current focus mode 'fixed'; use auto focus? false
04-18 22:31:02.105  13672-13684/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1843K, 35% free 7238K/11032K, paused 34ms, total 47ms
04-18 22:31:02.298  13672-14288/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1737K, 35% free 7175K/11032K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
04-18 22:31:02.590  13672-13685/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1761K, 35% free 7175K/11032K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
04-18 22:31:02.690  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:02.690  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:02.840  13672-14283/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1680K, 35% free 7175K/11032K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
04-18 22:31:03.157  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:03.157  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:03.212  13672-13684/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1769K, 36% free 7131K/11032K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
04-18 22:31:03.341  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:03.341  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:03.477  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:03.477  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:03.658  13672-14288/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1736K, 35% free 7175K/11032K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
04-18 22:31:03.868  13672-13685/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1718K, 35% free 7175K/11032K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
04-18 22:31:03.958  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:03.958  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.031  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.031  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.062  13672-14283/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1728K, 36% free 7131K/11032K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
04-18 22:31:04.135  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.135  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.208  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.209  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.309  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr D/com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView﹕ ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.309  13672-13672/com.pavan.secureqr W/System.err﹕ com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
04-18 22:31:04.342  13672-13684/com.pavan.secureqr D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1738K, 36% free 7131K/11032K, paused 26ms, total 26ms

Comment: did you get solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

No the QR-Code gets read, but doing a quick research shows that the [Exception](http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/ChecksumException.html) is thrown, because the checksum feature failed.

Comment: But isn't it just a knock off effect of QR code not being decoded.

Comment: I don't know, what you mean by the knock off effect, but did you make sure, that this error isn't caused by the focus of your camera, like it happened here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732135/checksumexception-in-zxing-qrcodereader-when-not-reading-a-qr-code-with-an-url

Comment: I haven't really built the .jar file . But just added a dependency . So I thought the QR code wasn't being decoded. Yea the focus is proper because I am debugging it on my mobile .

Comment: But the autofocus is deactivated. Please try to activate it just for testing. I don't think that it is a matter of the dependency...

Comment: I have given auto focus permission in manifest file . and how to enable it ??

Comment: Oh like it´s described here: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Zxing-Bar-code-reader-is-86481.S.5820198338095497218 this is only possible if you integrate it into your project. This seams to much work only for testing.